# What are the factors to consider when setting the depth of a decision tree?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees

In scikit learn, one of the parameters to set when instantiating a decision tree is the maximum depth. What are the factors to consider when setting the depth of a decision tree? Does larger depth usually lead to higher accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it also means you're likely to overfit to the training data, so you need to find the value that strikes a balance between accuracy and properly fitting the data. Deciding on the proper setting of the `max_depth` parameter is the task of the tuning process, via either Grid Search or Randomised Search with cross-validation.

This page from the scikit-learn documentation explains the process well: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html